# How to setup path (urls) for multiple Django applications in a single Django project

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a single Django project which has two different Django applications,  MyApp1 and MyApp2 (changed their names).

The structure is like this:

```
MyProject
   MyApp1
      static
      templates
      urls.py
      views.py
      ...
   MyProject
      settings.py
      urls.py
      ...
```

I wrote the MyApp2 as a separate application in a different Django project and integrated it with the MyProject project (pip install MyApp2). Here is the installed apps in the settings.py file:

```
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'MyApp1',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MyApp2',
]
```

These are the following paths (urls.py) of the MyProject.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp1/', include('myapp1.urls')),
    path('', include('myapp1.urls')),
    path('myapp2/',include('myapp2.urls')),
]
```

These are the following paths (urls.py) of the MyApp1:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

These are the following paths (urls.py) of the MyApp2:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login, name='login'),
    path('index', views.home, name='home'),
    path('dashboard_output', views.dashboard_output, name='dashboard_output'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

On the browser, if I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/ or http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp1 I get the view of the MyApp1.

On the browser, if I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp2 I get the view of the MyApp2 (the login page).

So far so good, but if I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp2/index the system directs me to the view of the myapp1 instead of the view of the myapp2. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening with these urls. Exactly which view do you get when you go to myapp2/index?

Comment: When I go to myapp2/index url, I am calling the home view which renders the index.html page of the MyApp2 application.

Comment: Yes but you said you got something else. What, exactly?

Comment: I am getting the home page of the MyApp1 instead of the MyApp2. MyApp1 and MyApp2 are totally different applications.

Comment: I wish you would be specific. I know they are separate applications. But are you saying that when you go to "/myapp2/index", instead of getting the result of myapp2.views.home, you get the result of myapp1.views.home?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening. It calls the myapp1.views.home. What I need is the myapp2.views.home to be called.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what is causing the problem. It has to do with templates. Check out this:
https://www.webforefront.com/django/customizedjangotemplates.html

It is really important how Django works. If you have multiple applications and if APP_DIRS is set to true ('APP_DIRS': True) in the settings.py file, it checks out all templates directories of each application in the order of the applications in the INSTALLED_APPS. Long story short, since I had index.html files in templates directories of both MyApp1 and MyApp2 applications, it was overriding the index.html file of the MyApp2's template directory with the index.html file of the MyApp1's template directory.

As a solution, I just added a subdirectory called myapp2 under the template directory in the MyApp2 application and included the subfolder name while rendering it.

```
MyProject
   MyApp1
      static
      templates
         index.html
         ... 
      urls.py
      views.py
      ...
   MyApp2
      static
      templates
         myapp2
           index.html
           ...
      urls.py
      views.py
      ...
   MyProject
      settings.py
      urls.py
      ...
```

As I said, I added the subdirectory name (myapp2/) to the render function's second parameter. Here it is:

```
...
return render(request, "myapp2/index.html", result)
```

I could add a subdirectory to the templates folder in the MyApp1 too but just didn't prefer it for now, because it really got a big application and didn't want to mess up with it.

Anyway, the solution worked!